# Why can't I import only one function from a module?

Tags: python, module

(Python 3.11.1)

I only want to use the split() method from the re module but it doesn't work.
My IDE says that re is not defined.

```
from re import split
def to_camel_case(text):
    first_big_letter = True if (65 <= ord(text[0]) <= 90) else False
    arr = re.split('-|_', text)
    
    
    
    return arr
```

When I import the whole re module like this:

```
import re
```

the function works

Comment: when you 'import re' you are importing whole module so you can access the functions with re.**** notations. but if you use 'from re import split' then you are importing just split function and no need to use re.**** , instead you can directly use split() function.

Comment: One clue here would be the complete error message and its context. If the _import_ had failed, you'd see an error on line 1. You are likely seeing an error on line 4, where you try to _use_ it. So the question isn't why you can't import the function, but why the call to `re.split` is failing. Please always include exact, complete error messages when asking questions here. Paraphrasing never adds clarity, and it often obscures important details.

Answer (score 0):

Yourself gave the answer. You can use what you import. If you import `re` by `import re` then `re` will be defined in your file. You will be able to access whatever `re` has inside, in particular calling `re.split` will be legal. But if you write `from re import split`, what have you imported? You imported `split`. The function `split` is defined in your file and `re` is not. So the interpreter has no idea what to do whenever it finds `re`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want both `re` and `split` to be bound in the current scope, use two import statements.

```
import re
from re import split
```

The first actually creates the module (or will, if `re` isn't already defined as a built-in module in your Python implementation, as it is in CPython). The second notes that the `re` module is already defined behaves the same as

```
split = re.split
```

(which you could use as well, though for multiple name bindings the `from ... import ...` is simpler.)

`from foo import ...` will *create* the module `foo` if necessary, but it won't bind the resulting module to the *name* `foo` in the current scope.

---

Related, and different, an import like

```
import urllib.parse
```

will import the module `urllib.parse`, but bind the name `urllib` to the package that contains the module. But

```
from urllib import parse
```

will import the same module, but bind the module to the name `parse`, leaving the package imported by not bound to any name.